# How to migrate to just 1 or 2 hg + svn repository hosts?

Tags: svn, mercurial, repository, google-code

I use svn + hg. Should I merge to just one or 2 repository hosts? Is there disadvantage in merging to just one or 2 repository hosts? I used hg (bitbucket, googlecode) and svn (xp-dev.com and googlecode). So if it matters to choose between bitbucket, xp-dev.com and googlecode, which one is best? I think the disadvantage with code.google is that it's open source and I'm indifferent towards bitbucket and xp-dev who both seem able to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's subjective question (and answers), bad for SO format. But I'll try to answer

1. Never used XP-Dev, can say nothing
2. GCode - only public repo, small space-limit
3. BitBucket - private repos (but free plain only for small team of 5 users), no space-limits, only hg/git without Subversion

From this point - BitBucket wins

But, if using Subversion is a must also, you can see at [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/home) as "All in one solution" (or [Assembla Portfoli](http://portfolio.assembla.com/)o):

- private and public "Spaces",
- 1Gb total for any amount of your separate spaces (free plain, paid plains differ),
- Git-Github repo/SVN-external SVN repo/HG/Perforce as SCM,
- rich set of ALM-tools (good Wiki, smart Tickets)